# Can't decipher capture file

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

I'm playing with airodump-ng and wireshark (I'm not a networking specialist). I have captured some packets from my network with airodump-ng and wanted to open them in wireshark, but they seem to be gibberish (instead of HTTP requests and stuff).

[image: wireshark screenshot]

This was my order of operations:

1. Run `airodump-ng --bbsid <myRouterMac> -c 1 -w <filename> <interface> --output-format pcap`, make some requests in browser (http, not https) and Ctrl-C.
2. Open Wireshark and open the file.
3. Add WPA-PSK generated key from Wireshark website generator.
4. Experiment with options [image: wireshark options]

I expected this to work, but it's not working. What may be the cause? What I have to do to make it work?

Comment: In the future, this may be better suited for the I formation security stack exchange site.

Comment: What happens if you set "Ignore the Protection bit" to "No"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a Wi-Fi traffic capture looks like a bunch of different random 802.2/LLC traffic with lots of different random DSAPs and SSAPs, it means your packet analyzer (Wireshark) is trying to interpret encrypted frames as if they were plaintext frames (i.e., as if they were never encrypted or already decrypted).

In your case, the most likely reason is that you didn't capture the 4-way WPA/WPA2 handshake (the EAPOL-key frames) when the client(s) in question joined the network this time.

Less likely reasons may be that you didn't enter your WPA/WPA2 passphrase or SSID correctly in the key generator, or you didn't copy the output of the key generator correctly and enter it correctly into the appropriate field in the Wireshark UI.

WPA- and WPA2-PSK generate per-client, per-session keys, based on a combination of the PSK (which is derived from the passphrase and SSID via PBKDF2 as you know) **in combination with** the nonces and other information exchanged during the 4-way key handshake at the beginning of the connection. So if you don't capture the 4-way handshake for a given connection, you can't decode any of the traffic from that connection.

Comment: I have a cap file with 4-way handshake and WPA passphrase is correct and it still didn't decipher it correctly. I will capture it once more and see if it works.

Comment: @AreWojciechowski As a double-check, see if you can successfully decode the example file at https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11

Answer (score 0):

Airodump-ng captures RAW 802.11 frames. You're seeing the 802.11 protocol here.

This is explained in more detail here

http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng

You may want to post this to https://security.stackexchange.com in the future.

Comment: So what should I do to convert raw 802.11 frames to 802.11 protocol?

Comment: What did you mean by step 3. Please elaborate on that.

Comment: Wireshark has to decrypt WPA encrypted frames, so I need to add wpa-psk key to Wireshark preferences generated using this: https://www.wireshark.org/tools/wpa-psk.html.

Comment: If you want to view the https:// traffic just use the display filter "http".  It's working, you're just also seeing all the overhead of the 802.11 protocol.

Comment: There is nothing when I use filter `http`.  I think that wireshark is not seeing everything.

Comment: Was the browser activity done on the same machine running the capture?

Comment: No, I've been capturing WiFi traffic that was made on the other computer on my network and I got those packets captured. I just can't find a way to read them using Wireshark.

Comment: It could be that your wifi card isn't capable of operating in permiscous mode. You can test this by repeat g the capture, creating some http traffic on the capturing machine and the filter g for http again.